# Click to Move Controller Not Working Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, controller, onclick

I'm following what looked to be a simple tutorial on setting up **mouse click movement** in Unity and my character is **not moving at all**. I've put a `Debug.Log` in the `ClickToMove()` method and discovered when I left click it does not execute the method.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVu3_IVCzys

Player Controller Script:
https://github.com/ItsPogle/Unity-Mouse-Click-Movement-Template/blob/main/Episode%201%20-%20Mouse%20Click%20Movement/Scripts/PlayerController.cs

Player Components:

[image]

I've installed the **Input System** and **AI Navigation** packages from the Unity Registry.

I have the Nav Mesh Agent Component attached to the player object along with the Player Controller script linked above. The Nav Mesh Surface is attached to the Environment game object which includes the ground plane.

The **CustomActions** has a move action with a **Left Mouse Button**  binding.

I would really appreciate any help.

Unity Version 2022.3.10f1

Answer (score 0):

I discovered The issue was to do with the Input system setting for the player. To fix it, go to

> Edit > Project Settings > Player

and find the **Active Input Handling** dropdown and select **"both"**.

And then in the inspector of the player character, I changed the **clickable layers** to **"everything"**.

The player now moves when the ground is clicked :)